# Using reactNative with GitHub and mixing between MAC and PC?

Tags: javascript, react-native, github

Someone how has got problems when using reactNative with GitHub and mixing between MAC and PC? We got problems when cloning a repository

After typing npm start we get following error message...

> react-native-scripts start

sh: /Users/juliafalk/Desktop/J3/node_modules/.bin/react-native-scripts: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 126

npm ERR! J3@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`

npm ERR! Exit status 126

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the J3@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/juliafalk/.npm/_logs/2018-03-28T07_09_02_393Z-debug.log
student251-74:J3 juliafalk$

This only occurs between MAC and PC and not between MAC and MAC or PC and PC.... Anyone that have had the same problem and that have any solutions for this??

Comment: Did you try adding a 'sudo' in case of mac. Might be the issue with file permission and how they are managed in different OS.

Comment: Don't use `sudo` as the first thing you try. There's no reason npm would need root permissions to fire up a React Native project. You're going to have to add more detail though like 1) how you are sharing the projects between the two OSes, and 2) what steps you used to setup it up on both OSes. Also, edit the question for better formatting (place your errors in code blocks).